# calling command-line utility from app

Tags: ios

Is it possible to call a command-line utility from a running app on iOS devices?

The utility is a binary executable and is supposed to be included in the app package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already are command line utilities (think iSSH) on the iPhone. If what you mean, however, is "can you use underlying UNIX system utilities" or "run a utility you bundle onto a iPhone shell", no it's not possible.

Apart from that, bundling an opensource utility with a closed source application will open *interesting* legal challenges, you would have to be very attentive to implications of licenses.

Comment: I want to ask the same question about android but SO says it is a duplicate. I don't think so. It's the same question for another platform. What have I to do now?

Comment: Reformulate your question to be very precise, in order to be clear enough that people won't think it is a duplicate?

Comment: Kheldar understood very well the question, @Will